# rebar: Missing application directory

Tags: erlang, rebar, reltool

I'm testing rebar on

- Windows 8 64Bis
- Erlang 64bits R15B02

I've compiled rebar from github code and created a basic app

```
$ mkdir testapp; cd testapp
$ mkdir rel
$ rebar create-app appid=testapp
$ echo "{sub_dirs, ["rel"]}." > rebar.config
$ cd rel
$ rebar create-node nodeid=testnode
$ cd -
$ rebar compile
$ rebar generate    
ERROR: generate failed while processing testapp/rel: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,"testapp: : Missing application directory."}
...
```

I'm reading the reltool documentation but i cant found anything about application dir the only relevant option is `incl_cond` but is defined by default by `rebar` command

#### src/testapp.app.src

```
{application, testapp,
 [
  {description, ""},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [
                  kernel,
                  stdlib
                 ]},
  {mod, { testapp_app, []}},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

#### rel/reltool.config

```
{sys, [
       {lib_dirs, []},
       {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
       {app_file, strip},
       {rel, "testapp", "1",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib,
         sasl,
         testapp
        ]},
       {rel, "start_clean", "",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib
        ]},
       {boot_rel, "testapp"},
       {profile, embedded},
       {incl_cond, derived},
       {mod_cond, derived},
       {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
       {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                           "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
       {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
       {app, testapp, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}]}
      ]}.

{target_dir, "testapp"}.

{overlay, [
           {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
           {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
           {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},
           {copy, "files/testapp", "bin/testapp"},
           {copy, "files/testapp.cmd", "bin/testapp.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript", "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
          ]}.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This might help you](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/erlang-programming/fr5ccgnBSck). *(quoted below in case the original link disappears)*

Not exactly sure what's the reason for that change for versions following R15B01 though.

> Thanks to Siri, reltool in R15B01 includes a really useful feature.
>
> Many Erlang projects are using the following structure:
>   
> ./src/foo.app.src
>   
> ./src/foo.erl
>   
> ./rel/reltool.config
>
> When you wanted to reference the application foo in
>   rel/reltool.config, you previously had three options:
>   
>   * project-local libs/ or apps/ directory
>   
>   * unsafe {lib_dirs, "../.."} reltool.config setting
>   
>   * rebar_reltool_link fake_lib_dir plugin
>
> Starting with R15B01 all you have to do now is specify
>   
> {app, foo, [{incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]}
>   
> in reltool.config for applications not in lib_dirs.
>
> Although R15B01 is still in development, this feature is complete and
>   can be used in the otp.git maint branch.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had to modify the default `rel/reltool.config` line

```
   {lib_dirs, []},
```

to

```
   {lib_dirs, ["../../"]},
```

Where the layout of my project is:

```
Makefile
ebin/   
rebar.config
rel/    
src/
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this guideline, 
https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Release-handling

If you're using R15B01 or newer change,

{app, exemplar, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]}

above way of mentioning path solved the application directory not found issue for me.